# How do you usually write really long & complex workers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building the feature called import_items.

The logic is somewhat complex and sequential:

```
# Step 1. See if User has a remote source set up.
# Step 2. If yes (it's set up) - load that CSV file.
# Step 3. Convert CSV to Hashes 
# Step 4. Reject CSV rows that don't belong to the user 
#         (export feed can have items of other users)
# Step 5. Convert remaining hashes into hashes my DB can accept
# Step 6. For each hash in that array start Item.delay.create(hash)
#         (want it to go through Sidekiq because user can import say 500 items, 
#          which takes time, some of them can fail etc)
```

If one step fails - all next steps should not be done.

And all this has to be done in background job.

How do you usually write this kind of feature?

The only way I thought of for now is break it into steps, and do a delayed job for each step:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def import_items
    self.delay.load_CSV if self.dms and self.dms_id
  end

  def load_CSV
    result = ... (loading CSV file, convert rows to hashes)
    self.delay.keep_only_user_items(result) if result
  end

  def keep_only_user_items(all_items)
    result = ... (rejecting wrong items)
    self.delay.convert_to_proper_hashes(result)
  end

  ... # etc
end
```

Is that a good way to go?

I just want to test each step to make sure they work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need DelayedJob here to return early, it will only complicate things. Just break the logic into small methods and don't proceed when there's error. In short, drop the `delay` from your code and you should be good.

> How do you usually write really long & complex methods?

You do not write long and complex methods. You write small and simple methods. It'll pay off.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def import_items
    load_CSV if self.dms and self.dms_id
  end

  def load_CSV
    result = ... (loading CSV file, convert rows to hashes)
    keep_only_user_items(result) if result
  end

  def keep_only_user_items(all_items)
    result = ... (rejecting wrong items)
    convert_to_proper_hashes(result)
  end
end
```

Comment: I wouldn't want to do a remote request and process 500 items with all callbacks all in the main thread..

Comment: Well, then delay only the root method. Don't delay the submethods.

Comment: Ha, but how do I test this? I mean the line `keep_only_user_items(result) if result`. I don't want all chain of methods to get triggered during testing.

Comment: With Sidekiq I could just check if next job is scheduled.

Comment: @SergeVinogradoff: `@user.should_receive(:keep_only_user_items)` in RSpec.

Comment: It won't trigger `:keep_only_user_items` ?

Comment: It shouldn't, IIRC. But you can always `stub` it before, just to be sure.